# why Aged Payable report are not accessible by some users in same company in odoo10

Tags: python, report, odoo-10

I am currently working in accounting module. As I logged as a User in a company, I run this 'model': `'account.aged.payable'` through the 'url': `'/account_reports/output_format/aged_payable/1'`.

I am facing access error

```
The requested operation cannot be completed due to security restrictions. 
Please contact your system administrator.
(Document type: res.partner, Operation: read)
```

I changed all the access rights on Record Rules and Access control lists for Partners through **Settings-->Technical-->Security-->Record Rules** .

code:

```
 class report_account_aged_payable(models.AbstractModel):
        _name = "account.aged.payable"
        _description = "Aged Payable"
        _inherit = "account.aged.partner"

        @api.model
        def get_lines(self, context_id, line_id=None):
            if type(context_id) == int:
                context_id = self.env['account.context.aged.payable'].search([['id', '=', context_id]])
            new_context = dict(self.env.context)
            new_context.update({
                'date_to': context_id.date_to,
                'aged_balance': True,
                'context_id': context_id,
                'company_ids': context_id.company_ids.ids,
                'account_type': 'payable',
            })
            return self.with_context(new_context)._lines(context_id, line_id)
```

if I use `sudo()` on above return line as return `self.with_context(new_context)`.`sudo()._lines(context_id, line_id)` then I am accessing the report.
Without using `sudo()` how I access the Aged Payable Report?
Kindly help me to solve this issue.